# Sequences that represent different drawing of chords?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, big-list, partitions, bipartite-graphs

In combinatorics, there are special kinds of sequences, in which their terms represent the number of different ways that we can draw chords with some properties.

Actually, my question is motivated by the following examples of what I have mentioned earlier.

> 1. [Motzkin number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motzkin_number) (The number of different ways of drawing non-intersecting chords on a circle between n points)
> 2. [Bell number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number) (the number of partitions of a set of size n, in this case the drawing of the chords is described in the link)
> 3. [Catalan number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number)(number of non [crossing partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncrossing_partition) of some sets)

My question is that, can you, please, tell me similar sequences?

Comment: https://oeis.org/search?q=chords&language=english&go=Search

Comment: Perfect matchings. Perfect matchings with restrictions on the crossing number and or on the nesting number.

Comment: You linked to the Wikipedia page on Bell numbers. I see no "drawing of chords" there and searches of the page for "chord" and "matching" give no hits. How are Bell numbers counts of ways to draw chords?

Comment: @DouglasZare I think the link between the chords and bell number is that; the bell number tells the number of different partitions of a finite set. Present the elements of a set by points and if two points are in the same part we can draw a chord between them.

Comment: I don't think that's naturally described as drawing chords, and it's misleading to say "the drawing of the chords is described in the link."

Comment: @DouglasZare You are right probably I should have written it in an efficient way. But I think there is a link between them.

Comment: To put it more clearly: Bell numbers count the systems of chords that can be drawn in such a way that every pair of chords sharing an endpoint is part of a triangle.

Comment: For the Motzkin numbers and Catalan numbers, the chords are naturally drawn in a plane. In that description of the Bell numbers, there doesn't seem to be a meaningful plane on which the chords are drawn.

Comment: Many examples are given in Flajolet and Noy, Analytic combinatorics of chord diagrams, INRIA Rapport de recherche #3914, March 2000, online at http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/FlNo00.pdf

Comment: See also Pilaud and Rué, Analytic combinatorics of chord and hyperchord diagrams with $k$ crossings, Advances in Applied Mathematics, Volume 57, June 2014, Pages 60-100.

Comment: Have you had a look at those references, 137?

Answer (score 1):

You should at least include the [double factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial) (chord diagrams in which each of $2n$ points has exactly one chord incident to it — apparently these are also called Brauer diagrams).

Comment: Thank you this kind of examples is what I am looking for